# I am trying to install kivy but pip is giving me this error

Tags: python, pip

Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-9rd60o0h/kivy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-h2wevr4m-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-9rd60o0h/kivy/

Comment: What exact version of python do you use? Do you do this in virtualenv? What is operation system? Just tried to pip install kivy on python 3.7 in newly created virtualenv on MacOS mojave, it was successful

Comment: I am using ubunt 18.04 the python version is 3.6.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error code 1 is "permission denied" - most likely, as you're on Ubuntu, I'd guess you're trying to install the module globally. Either

- `pip install --user kivy` to install is into your user's local environment, or
- `sudo pip install kivy` to install it globally, as root